# How $u$ equal $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, inner-products, cross-product

I have  some confusion in Apostol calculas  volume $1$

My doubt is given below [image]

Comment: Well, what happens when you take the dot product with $N$ as the text suggests?

Comment: Here s , t , u all are scalars    ,  If we take  dot product  How $0$ ?@lulu

Comment: What happened when you rewrote the equation $X-P=sA+tB+uN$ by applying the dot product of $N$ with each side of the equation? What did the equation look like? How did you make use of knowledge built up earlier in the proof? For example, how did you make use of the knowledge that $X-P$ is orthogonal to $N$?

Comment: What is $(X-P)\cdot N$?  What is $A\cdot N$?  What is $B\cdot N$? Keep in mind that, for a scalar, $\lambda$, we have $(\lambda \vec u)\cdot \vec v=\lambda(\vec u\cdot \vec v)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher if $(X-P) $is orthogonal to $N$  then  $NA = NB= NN =0$

Comment: okss  i got  its  now   @lulu

Comment: sorry  I was  thinking  N is orthogonal to N.

Comment: It's a bad idea to write things like $NA$ for vectors $N,A$.  In this text, both dot and cross products are discussed.  How is the reader to guess which one you are thinking of?

Comment: i was thinking dot product     actually i was  reading this  theorem  so fast  ,so  i made a mistake  in my thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $N$ is orthogonal to $X-P$, to $A$ and to $B$. Therefore,$$0=N.(X-P)=N.(sA+tB+uN)=u\|N\|^2.$$